# Configuring SAGA Tools on QGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, saga

I'm trying to use the process saga:paramemeltonruggednessnumber as following :

```
melton_saga = processing.run("saga:parememeltonruggednessnumber",
         {'DEM' : path_filled,
          'AREA' : path_area,
          'ZMAX' : path_zmax,
          'MRN' : melton_layer})
```

It makes me the following error :

```
call saga_cmd ta_hydrology "ParameMelton Ruggedness Number" -DEM "C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpff7k_q4j\filled.sgrd" -AREA "C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpff7k_q4j\area.tif" -ZMAX "C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpff7k_q4j\zmax.tif" -MRN "C:/Users/Utilisateur/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_HIbIsN/94cd52427f7048f5b877831b3172d028/melton.tif"
             Error: select a tool
```

The Saga Gis command line must be like :

```
Usage: saga_cmd ta_hydrology 23 [-DEM <str>] [-AREA <str>] [-ZMAX <str>] [-MRN <str>]
  -DEM:<str>    Elevation
    Grid (input)
  -AREA:<str>   Catchment Area
    Grid (output)
  -ZMAX:<str>   Maximum Height
    Grid (output)
  -MRN:<str>    Melton Ruggedness Number
    Grid (output)
```

The problem here is that i'm missing the number 23, how can I implant it ?

Comment: On which version of QGIS are you working on ?

Comment: Actually I have Qgis 3.10 and 3.14

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would try to run the tool within a model to check if the issue is related to your QGIS version or not. I've quickly tried on QGIS 3.1 & 3.12 and the tool works smoothly on both version.

Here is the script if it can help you out:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
import processing


class Modle(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        pass

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Paramemelton ruggedness number
        alg_params = {
            'DEM': 'F:/test/MNT_brouillon.tif',
            'AREA': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'MRN': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'ZMAX': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ParamemeltonRuggednessNumber'] = processing.run('saga:paramemeltonruggednessnumber', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Modèle'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Modèle'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Modle()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sadly your script gives me the same error : Error: select a tool
I've tried to run it on Qgis 3.10 and 3.14, and does not work on both..
I've tried to replace the ta-hydrology.dll of Saga with a most recent one, but the error still occurs...
Any idea ?

Comment: Does the tool work if you run it directly from the processing toolbox ?

Comment: No.. but I've tried to run it directly from Saga and it works

Comment: That's weird, it works fine on my QGIS 3.10 ! Did you try to uninstall / reinstall QGIS (just in case) ?

Comment: Yeah.. I made a clean installation yesterday..
As you said, pretty weird !